# unable to integrate datatables into a rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I am using the no configuration option and have taken the following steps:

1. put the js files into root/public/javascripts
2. put the image files into root/public/images
3. put the demo css files into root/public/stylesheets
4. put css call in the head section of my layout file

   ```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "demo_table", :media => "all" %>
   ```
5. put the initialization script in the head section of my layout file:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable();
   } );
   </script >
   ```
6. first line of my table layout is:

   ```
   <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; " id="example">
   ```

I restarted my server. Nothing happens. What am i missing?

Comment: @bpeterson76, Thanks for the suggestion. Tried to set up zero configuration option to no avail.No views on this question after quite a while. I'll give it a little more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the [RailsDatatables plugin](https://github.com/phronos/rails_datatables) in my rails apps without any problem. Maybe give that a try?

Comment: thanks. I am committed to making this work, but am getting an error that i'll put in another post. If i get this working, I'll accept your answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The zero config relies on having a properly formatted table, which your example isn't showing.  It must also have `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements to render properly.  Ensure that's properly setup first.

Second, open the page in Chrome or Firefox, view source.  Click on the links to the Datatables.js and Datatables.css files as well as Jquery.js (or whatever each of these files is named)  Do they open?  If not, there's your problem.

Javascript is essentially platform independent.  Sure, you get information TO the script in different manners in Rails, PHP, .net, etc, but there's no reason that this doesn't work in any of the major scripting language.

Comment: I had the <thead> and <tbody> elements. Will start with your second step.